# How to load external F# script file and use it in F# interactive?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I would like to load one or more `.fsx` files into the F# interactive and have all the functions defined in the `.fsx` files in scope so that I can directly use the functions in the console.

The `#load` directive executes the `.fsx` file specified, but then I am no longer able to use those functions in the `.fsx` file.  Any workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suspect that the script you are loading is not in a module which may be causing your problem.  Just add

```
module Script1
```

in the first script and then you can do

```
#load "Script1.fsx"
open Script1
```

and your functions will be accessible

Comment: Then you lose the ability of running `Script1.fsx` independently.

Comment: Yeah, this works if I'm in Windows... But if I use Mono on my Mac it still doesn't work.

Comment: Doing it this way allows you to use your *.fs source files in your *.fsx too!

Answer (score 39):

If you don't declare a module in fsx file, it implicitly creates a module the same name as file name.

Therefore, you can always refer to another fsx file using fully qualified names or opening respective modules before use. For example, in `Script2.fsx` you can do:

```
#load "Script1.fsx"

open Script1

// Use functions in Script1.fsx
// ...
```

Comment: Note that the implicit module always uses Title case regardless of the file name

Comment: Seems like the implicit module is always created unless you declare a 'whole of file' module in the .fsx. That is to say, if you put the equals sign after your module, _even if that's the only one in the script_, that module gets put in an implicit module.

Answer (score 1):

For running script from a terminal and using it in the interactive mode you can add the next directives:

```ml
#if INTERACTIVE
#else
module Script
#endif
```