# error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'X' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am trying to run my code interactively in an fsx file. I have loaded all the dlls required, I then try to load the required files with #load but when I load the "Utlities.fs" file which depends on a function in the top file "HttpGetExchangeRate.fs" i get the error "Utilities.fs(88,42): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'getExchangeRates' is not defined"

Dose the 'getExchangeRates' not get defined when i load  "HttpGetExchangeRate.fs"as in the image below or an I missing something?

```
#load "HttpGetExchangeRate.fs"
#load "Utilities.fs"

open System
open FsCheck
open NUnit.Framework
open HttpClient

InvoiceApp.Http.getExchangeRates "EUR" "USD"

InvoiceApp.Math.convertInvoicingCurrencyToEuro 200.00M "EUR"
```

Here is an image of the error message
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your scenario correctly, this is due to a bug in how namespaces are handled in FSI. The workaround is to `open` the namespace you need before `#load`ing the second file

```
#load "HttpGetExchangeRate.fs"
open InvoiceApp
#load "Utilities.fs"
```

That should get you unblocked for now, the bug [has since been fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/44) (F# 4.0/VS 2015 will have the fix).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running into the issue described in this question with implicit modules in fsi.

[How to load external F# code and use it in fsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545472/how-to-load-external-f-source-code-and-use-it-in-f-interactive)